# How to list all the methods in a Module using Pry navigation?

Tags: ruby, pry

The feature that Pry provides using 'cd' to change the content and using 'ls' to show all the methods and variable in it.

My question is how can I use it in Module, like show all the method in `Math` module

Comment: this always worked for me: `cd Math` `ls`  `Math.methods: acos  acosh  asin  asinh  atan  atan2` ... does not this work for you?

Answer (score 3):

```
[4] pry(main)> ls Math -m
Math.methods: acos  acosh  asin  asinh  atan  atan2  atanh  cbrt  cos  cosh  erf  erfc  exp  frexp  gamma  hypot  ldexp  lgamma  log  log10  log2  sin  sinh  sqrt  tan  tanh
[5] pry(main)>
```